# When trying to display a list of books from the database on the jsp page , i have Null value for 'password'

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, tomcat9

I has been develop webapp via servelt + jsp , apache tomcat and postgresql and have problems with connection to database. I don't understand how it's decide.
Exception :

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Something unusual has occurred to cause the driver to fail. Please report this exception.
at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:285)
at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:681)
at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:229)
at org.postgresql.ds.common.BaseDataSource.getConnection(BaseDataSource.java:103)
at org.postgresql.ds.common.BaseDataSource.getConnection(BaseDataSource.java:87)
at ua.dragunov.library.dao.UserDAO.getAll(UserDAO.java:93)
at ua.dragunov.library.service.UserService.getAll(UserService.java:33)
at ua.dragunov.library.servlets.BookListServlet.doGet(BookListServlet.java:19)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:687)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:889)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1743)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Null value for 'password'
at org.postgresql.shaded.com.ongres.scram.common.util.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:41)
at org.postgresql.shaded.com.ongres.scram.common.util.Preconditions.checkNotEmpty(Preconditions.java:55)
at org.postgresql.shaded.com.ongres.scram.client.ScramSession$ServerFirstProcessor.clientFinalProcessor(ScramSession.java:128)
at org.postgresql.jre7.sasl.ScramAuthenticator.processServerFirstMessage(ScramAuthenticator.java:147)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.doAuthentication(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:778)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:161)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:213)
at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:51)
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.\<init\>(PgConnection.java:225)
at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:465)
at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:264
```

UserDAO code :

```
@Override
    public List<User> getAll() {
        List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();
        try(Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection()) {
            Statement getAllStatement = connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet resultSet = getAllStatement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM users");

            while (resultSet.next()) {
                User user = new User();
                user.setId(resultSet.getLong(1));
                user.setLogin(resultSet.getString(2));
                user.setEmail(resultSet.getString(3));
                user.setPassword(resultSet.getString(4));

                users.add(user);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

        return users;
    }
```

My DataSource code :

```
public class LibraryDataSource {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(LibraryDataSource.class);

    private LibraryDataSource() {}

    public static DataSource getLibraryDataSource() {
        PGSimpleDataSource libraryDatasource = new PGSimpleDataSource();

        try(FileReader propertiesReader =
                    new FileReader("src/main/resources/application.properties")) {

            Properties databaseProperties = new Properties();
            databaseProperties.load(propertiesReader);

            libraryDatasource.setURL(databaseProperties.getProperty("databaseUrl"));
            libraryDatasource.setUser(databaseProperties.getProperty("databaseUser"));
            libraryDatasource.setPassword(databaseProperties.getProperty("databasePassword"));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            LOGGER.info("LibraryDataSource::getLibraryDataSource : ", e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOGGER.info("LibraryDataSource::getLibraryDataSource : ", e);
        }


        return libraryDatasource;
    }


}
```

I tried to choose any version of tomcat and i was test on main method and in main method it's work. All data from the database is pulled, but have some problems on server

Comment: Thanks , I have a look at these topics and will try to fix my question. But maybe are you have some ideas for my problem

Comment: `src/main/resources/application.properties` is unlikely to be found at runtime, so no file is found, which you ignore (only logging), so the data source then isn't (fully) configured.

Comment: But I test this through the main method and its works.  All configuration is pulled from the properties file either I don't understand something? It is not worked only on tomcat server

Comment: Never ever use relative disk file system paths in a Java class which is in turn bundled in a JAR or WAR file. See abovelinked duplicate for proper approaches.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your advice was very helpfully for me)